# how to kill a cmd process without killing others cmds?

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, jenkins

I'm working on a batch file that is supposed to START a process (CMD) and then it should kill the process after finished. Problem is, that Imagename is cmd.exe and the other problem is that it should be running on Jenkins. 
This is what I have tested:

- Getting PID with wmic using name of window to find process -> Failed  at Jenkins
- Taskkill by naming the window-> Failed because Jenkins does not
  display windows due to security issues.
- Taskkill by imagename -> Failed because there are other cmd processes
  running at the same time
- Taskkill with pid but pid from the last cmd started. -Works but it is
  not very safe.

I couldn´t understand how wmic works but as I see, I cannot start a process with a command like with START command.

Conditions:

- It can't be kill after some time because I need the output from the
  mergetool and sometimes mergetool can take too long.
- It should run at same time with other (cmd) processes // Jenkins

My question, is there a way of getting the PID from the START Command?

Here are some questions that helped me a lot!
[Windows batch file : PID of last process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677462/windows-batch-file-pid-of-last-process)
[Compare number of a specific process to a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210438/compare-number-of-a-specific-process-to-a-number)

CODE:

```
set "console_name=cmd.exe"
set "git_command=%gitcmd% mergetool ^>output.txt"
tasklist /FI "imagename eq %console_name%" /NH /FO csv > task-before.txt
START "mergetool_w" CMD /c %git_command%
tasklist /FI "imagename eq %console_name%" /NH /FO csv > task-after.txt
for /f "delims=, tokens=2,*" %%A in ('fc /L /LB1  task-before.txt task-after.txt') do set pid=%%A
pid=!pid:"=!
echo pid is %pid%
TASKKILL /t /pid %pid% /f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually use [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) for checking what tasks have been added after your `start` command line, relying on your files `task-before.txt` and `task-after.txt`:

```cmd
findstr /LXVG:task-before.txt task-after.txt
```

Due to a [nasty bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8921253), this might under some circumstances lead to an unexpected output. To prevent that, add the `/I` option, if you can live with case-insensitive searches:

```cmd
findstr /ILXVG:task-before.txt task-after.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's very possible. I'm going to take code from my previous awnser on another post here: [Stop Execution of Batch File after 20 Seconds and move to Next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443433/stop-execution-of-batch-file-after-20-seconds-and-move-to-next/51483868#51483868)

I want to first assume "mergetool_w" is the name of the CMD you are opining with the `start`...

The way you want to go about this is to search the `tasklist` for your console **title** and extract the `PID#` out of the context. The `find` suffix can be used to "Filter" the results along with `tokens=2` to extract only the `PID#`.

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%# in ('tasklist /v ^| find "mergetool_w"') do set PID=%%#
```

From there, you can now kill this new window using the `taskkill /pid` command. The `PID#` is stored in the string `%PID%` so the command is simple:

```
taskkill /pid %PID% /t /f
```

Finaly, it looks as if you are trying to "Log" the data so feel free to put `> text-task.txt` where it's needed.

Comment: I haven't been able to check/test but, I assume because the `Find` command is also using the string `mergetool_w`, would it therefore follow that it would match itself in the `tasklist` output and possibly return the incorrect `PID`? _It was my understanding that the command within the `For` parentheses is run in a separate `cmd.exe` instance, which would show up in `TaskList` `find`ing `mergetool_w` and `Console`_.

Comment: @Compo No this command will find any console that is named `mergetool_w` and give it's `PID`. Give it a shot, make a basic batch file and use the `Title` command with `pause`. Now of course, if two consoles are named the same thing, you may have some issues as you will get two results.

Comment: I said I was unable to check or test, because I rarely have access to a computer, especially a Windows one. I accept your answer to my question; in doing so I assume that `/V`erbose outputs the `Window Title` but not the `Command Line`.

Comment: @Compo That is correct, however `^| find "Console"` is not needed for this but does not hurt the result. I will be editing my response.

Comment: Hi John, I tested the way you suggest but unfortunately, Jenkins does not display windows, and the name is never retrieved, that's why I searched for a different solution. But I understand your approach. However with help from @aschipfl, my script now does what I want. Thank you!